# Android: Get row position from list view

Tags: android, listview

I have ListView. Every row has TextView with some text. And also by default every row has it's position (int value). Can I get row position by text which is in Text View ?

Comment: You're going to have to explain yourself a bit better. Your question is not clear at all.

Comment: As dmon says its not at all clear what you are trying to achieve, please state more clearly what you want to do and also provide code showing what you have attempted so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you register to receive click events, then the position will come with the event.  If you need to find the position outside the scope of click events, then store the position with the view via setTag().